# Why is this Route's model updated in only 2 of 3 cases? - Ember.js 2.3

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, routes, navigation

I'm using Ember.js 2.3. I have a parent `Route` that looks like this:

```
App.AppRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    Ember.RSVP.hash
      projects: @store.findAll "project"
      clients: @store.findAll "client"
      consultants: @store.findAll "consultant"
      practiceAreas: @store.findAll("practice_area").then (practice_areas) ->
        practice_areas.sortBy "displayName"
```

I have a child `Route` looking like:

```
App.AppProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    hash = @modelFor "app"
    hash["project"] = @store.findRecord "project", params.project_id
      .then (p) -> p
    hash["workWeeks"] = @store.query "work-week", project_id: params.project_id
      .then (weeks) -> weeks
    console.log _.keys hash
    Ember.RSVP.hash hash
```

The template for the child `Route` contains:

```
  <hr/>
  {{add-consultant project=model.project consultants=model.consultants addConsultant="didAddConsultant"}}
</div>
```

Then the `add-consultant` component contains a computed property:

```
remainingConsultants: Ember.computed "project", "project.consultants.[]", "consultants.[]", ->
  already_involved = @get "project.consultants"
  remaining        = @get "consultants"

  already_involved.forEach (ai) ->
    remaining = remaining.reject (r) -> r.get("id") is ai.get("id")

  remaining.sortBy "displayName"
```

---

### Case 1

When I navigate directly to a project, such as `http://localhost/#/app/project/27`, the `Route`s `model` hook correctly queries the server for data and renders the template and components.

### Case 2

When I navigate directly to a project, then manually change the project ID in the URL (say from `http://localhost/#/app/project/27` to `http://localhost/#/app/project/28` and press `Enter`, the `Route` `model` hooks update, and the template and components are correctly rerendered.

### Case 3

However - and this is my confusion - navigating to a project by clicking a link (say, from a list of Projects using the `{#link-to}` helper) - even if I first visit the page sucessfully as in Case 1 or Case 2 and then immediately navigate back to the same Project, I get an error:

```
TypeError: already_involved is undefined
```

Looking deeper, it turns out that `@get "project"` itself is undefined.

What is different about using `{#link-to}` over "direct" navigation that causes this? Is it an error I made in defining my Route model heirarchy? Am I missing some kind of event hook?

---

**EDIT 1:** If there's a smarter or more idiomatic way to define these types of hierarchical `model` hooks maybe that would obviate this issue?

**EDIT 2:** The `Router`:

```
this.route "app", ->
  this.route "projects"
  this.route "project", path: "/project/:project_id"
```

Comment: Can you include your router as well?

Comment: Since you are returning hashes from the `model()` hooks, you might want to pass the id to the `link-to` as opposed to the object, to force the `model()` hook to trigger.

Comment: Keep in mind that `link-to` _skips the `model` hook_. What you pass to the `link-to` helper should be exactly the same as what the `model` hook would return. In your case, an object with `project` and `workWeeks` entries.

Comment: @GJK is this in the Guide somewhere that I missed? Maybe I just misread: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/templates/links/ it doesn't seem to indicate that `model()` hooks won't run when using `link-to`, but assuming that _is_ the case, what's the alternative? Is there a different invocation of `link-to` or an alternative helper that does trigger the `model()` hook?

Comment: @ChrisTonkinson see the code sample in [`model()`'s api documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model). you can pass the id to force the hook, like I mention in the previous comment.

Comment: ChrisTonkinson, it does that because the model hook is meant to fetch the model. If you already have the model (because you pass it in to the helper), it doesn't need to fetch it. (Although you can pass an ID in as locks said).

Comment: Thanks all, this actually makes perfect sense now. The problem was indeed that I was passing an Object instead of an ID to `link-to`. Anyone want to post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transitions, triggered by either the `link-to` helper or `transitionTo`/`transitionToRoute` have two "modes". The transition can either trigger the model hooks (`beforeModel`, `model`, `afterModel`), or not.

To skip the model hooks, you can pass an object to the transition, e.g. `{{link-to "Profile" user}}`. Ember.js interprets this as you already having the necessary information, and thusly skips the hooks that would load said information.

To force the model hooks though, you can pass a string or an integer to the transition, e.g. `{{link-to "Profile" 1}}` or `{{link-to "Profile" user.id}}`. This will use the value passed to the transition to fill out the dynamic segment of the route, and Ember.js interprets this as the data necessary not being loaded yet, and thusly triggers the hooks.

Since your model hook returns a hash, it is advantageous to force the hooks so everything loads appropriately.

You can consult the [documentation for the model hook](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) for further information.